# Beginner question: abstracts comparison

Tags: text-mining, artificial-intelligence

We want to compare the abstract of a chosen article with that of several article, to identify those that would be more "relevant" from a content point of view. Question:

- Do you know any tool/method that can help us do this?
- Can we use the Lucene score for this purpose? Or is this score suited only for rankings based on few words and no actual pieces of text?